# Multiple variable assignments with single column as result

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  0 | Foo  |
|  1 | Bar  |
+----+------+
```

Based on the table rows I want to calculate a ranking based on each row, so that a query like

```
SELECT *, [calculation] AS ranking 
FROM table 
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

would return something like

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | Name | Ranking |
+----+------+---------+
|  0 | Bar  |       3 |
|  1 | Foo  |       1 |
+----+------+---------+
```

My problem is, that I need to perform multiple assignments per row without getting more columns; basically something like

```
@ranking:= 0
IF(Name LIKE $firstTerm, @ranking := @ranking + 1, @ranking := @ranking)
IF(Name LIKE $secondTerm, @ranking := @ranking + 1, @ranking := @ranking)
IF(Name LIKE $thirdTerm, @ranking := @ranking + 1, @ranking := @ranking)
```

For each row, so that in the end I have either 0, 1, 2 or 3 as one extra column for each entry in my table

EDIT: In theory a dynamically generated query like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN
      (NAME LIKE $firstTerm AND NAME NOT LIKE $secondTerm AND NAME NOT LIKE $thirdTerm)
      OR (NAME NOT LIKE $firstTerm AND NAME LIKE $secondTerm AND NAME NOT LIKE $thirdTerm)
      OR (NAME NOT LIKE $firstTerm AND NAME NOT LIKE $secondTerm AND Name LIKE $thirdTerm) THEN 1
  WHEN (Name LIKE $firstTerm AND Name LIKE $secondTerm AND Name NOT LIKE $thirdTerm)
    OR (Name NOT LIKE $firstTerm AND Name LIKE $secondTerm AND Name LIKE $thirdTerm) THEN 2
  WHEN (Name LIKE $firstTerm AND Name LIKE $secondTerm AND Name LIKE $thirdTerm) THEN 3
  ELSE 0
) DESC;
```

would work as expected, but you can probably imagine where this is going if we have more than 3 terms!

Comment: Tell us more about that calculation

Comment: It's supposed to be multiple LIKE comparisons, so the more matches it has, the higher it's ranked

Comment: @Strawberry I edited my question to be more correct (added a LIKE statement example)

Comment: Why so shy? why not make a real query result based on a real data set and real criteria. This abstraction is just confusing.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Well currently [calculation] is a placeholder for the right syntax for the assignments mentioned below.  Of course my real table is bigger, but the other stuff is just not relevant (just adding more table names which aren't used in this scenario)

Comment: And currently there is no real data set, just me calling example entries `this is an example`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
    IF(Name like $firstTerm, 1, 0) + 
    IF(Name like $secondTerm, 1, 0) as Ranking 
  FROM table ORDER BY Ranking DESC;
```

However, if the dataset gets big, and the calculation complex, using a search engine (elasticsearch, solr) would be more efficient and more flexible.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks! Should have thought about that!